# gradient while zooming in canvas android?

Tags: android, canvas, paint

I am drawing gradient text in canvas.While zooming its giving completely different behaviour

```
 textShader=new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, paint.getTextSize(),
            new int[]{color,secondary_color},
            new float[]{0, 1}, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
     paint.setShader(textShader);
```

while zooming

```
     paint.setTextSize(size*scale);// scale is a zooming factor
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
textShader=new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, paint.getTextSize(),
            new int[]{color,secondary_color},
            null, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
```

as the docs say the default is to evenly distribute the colors.

If no effect, call `paint.setShader(textShader)` again after the zoom in order to force recalculate the positions.